# How to make UI responsive while calling external exe in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am writing a WPF program which use a exe file to capture data from a hardware. It takes around 2 seconds to finish a single call. And I have use this exe multiple times (>500) back to back with different arguments. I've to wait for each process to finish before the next call.Because, I can't run multiple exe same time. The hardware doesn't support it. In the mean time I've show an update to the UI and also keep the UI responsive for canceling the task anytime.

I'm confused about what to and how to use async-await, Dispatcher.BeginInvoke or Task.run to solve my problem. Any help or idea will be highly appreciated.

```
    ObservableCollection < String > fileNames = new ObservableCollection < string > ();
    //fileNames is used to show the file names a ListBox in UI. It have to be
    // updated in real time.

    private void BtnStartCapture_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= CaptureSettings.NoOfFrames; i++) {
            String currentFile;
            if (CaptureSettings.CkBoard1 == true) {

                currentFile = CaptureSettings.CaptureFrame(1, i);
                fileNames.Add(currentFile);
            }

            if (CaptureSettings.CkBoard2 == true) {
                currentFile = CaptureSettings.CaptureFrame(2, i);
                fileNames.Add(currentFile);
            }

        }

    }

    internal String CaptureFrame(int boardId, int frameNo) {

        string arg = createCommandLIneArgument(boardId, frameNo);
        try {
            ProcessStartInfo pInfo1 = new ProcessStartInfo {
                FileName = "GrabberTest1.exe",
                Arguments = arg,
                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
            };

            var process1 = Process.Start(pInfo1);
            process1.WaitForExit();

            return Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(arg);
        } catch(Exception) {
            return "Failed " + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(arg);
        }
    }

private void BtnCancelCapture_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
//to do
}
```

Comment: You're wanting asynchronous calls to this external application to occur... but you always want to wait for its completion before moving on?  Sorry, I'm a bit confused, as it seems like your current implementation does the job for you - so what do you want about the outcome to behave differently in incorporating asynchronous calls?  To be clear: I like your question, but I don't understand the change you're wanting to make, and its reasoning.

Comment: I've to wait for the process to finish before the next call as I can't run multiple instance of the exe same time and also show a update to the UI. In my curernt implementation the UI freezes and show update after end of all exe calls. I don't know how to accomplish it.

Comment: You are sending UI thread To CaptureFrame and its dng that work so the ui will be unresponsive so u can use thread to do that work. I will check once wt I can do.

Comment: What does `WaitForExit` do?

Comment: @sumit You do *not* in fact need to block the UI by waiting for another process to complete just to avoid starting another external process before it finishes.  You just need to *not start another process* while one is still in process.  You don't need to block the UI to do that.

Comment: WaitForExit wait for the process to finish. As far I understand it's making sure the execution finished.

Comment: Yeah, but WaitForExit is called on the UI thread (via the click handler). Thus WaitForExit **blocks the UI thread** while it waits for the process to finsih.

Comment: "_I've to wait for each process to finish before the next call_" Note that if you want your UI to be not blocked, your button `BtnStartCapture` would still be active/clickable while your process is running, allowing you to click it and start another process while the first other process is still running. I guess you need to think and work out your application logic more thoroughly if you do not want to block/freeze your UI and also making sure that you/the user can only start another process if a previously started process has exited...

Comment: @Fildor You don't need to start a new thread to start a new process.  The work is *already in a separate process*.  There's no need for any new threads.  It's already doing one better.

Comment: @Fildor Creating a new thread just do do nothing but sit there and wait is pointless.  The only thing it does is waste system resources.  If you don't want to block the current thread until a `Process` finishes you don't call `WaitForExit` in another thread, you just *don't call `WaitForExit`*.

Comment: @Fildor Good thing `Process` goes out of it's way to give you a way of being notified when it finishes, so that you can do any work that may be required when it is done.  Just like tasks do.

Comment: @sumit let me know once u checked the answer I will delete it.

Comment: @Servy [Process.Exited](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.exited?view=netframework-4.8) dough! You beat me to it! Totally forgot about it.

Comment: @elgonzo I was thinking hiding the start button all together and show a cancel button. I didn't think it through as I was stuck in the earlier stage. I don't even know how to implement the cancelling mechanism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got 3 questions here:

1. How do I wait for a process to exit without blocking the UI thread?
2. How do I prevent a button from being clicked again until it finishes?
3. How do I cancel?

That's a ***lot*** for a single Stack Overflow question; in the future, please only ask one question at a time.

> How do I wait for a process to exit without blocking the UI thread?

You could use `TaskCompletionSource<T>` to hook into `Exited` as such:

```
public static Task<int> WaitForExitedAsync(this Process process)
{
  var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
  EventHandler handler = null;
  handler = (_, __) =>
  {
    process.Exited -= handler;
    tcs.TrySetResult(process.ExitCode);
  };
  process.Exited += handler;
  return tcs.Task;
}
```

However, this code has a few caveats:

1. You must set `Process.EnableRaisingEvents` to `true` before the process starts.
2. You must call `WaitForExitedAsync` before the process starts.
3. When `Exited` is raised, that does *not* mean that the stdout/stderr streams are finished. The only way to flush those streams is to call `WaitForExit` (after the process has exited). Not exactly intuitive.

For simplicity, you may just want to call `WaitForExit` on a background thread instead. That would use an extra unnecessary thread, but for a GUI app, that isn't critical.

In your code, you can push `CaptureFrame` off to a background thread:

```
private async void BtnStartCapture_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  for (int i = 1; i <= CaptureSettings.NoOfFrames; i++)
  {
    String currentFile;
    if (CaptureSettings.CkBoard1 == true)
    {
      currentFile = await Task.Run(() => CaptureSettings.CaptureFrame(1, i));
      fileNames.Add(currentFile);
    }

    if (CaptureSettings.CkBoard2 == true)
    {
      currentFile = await Task.Run(() => CaptureSettings.CaptureFrame(2, i));
      fileNames.Add(currentFile);
    }
  }
}
```

Note that [`async void` is used here *only* because this is an event handler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx). Normally, you should avoid `async void`.

> How do I prevent a button from being clicked again until it finishes?

One common pattern is to disable the button while it is running, as such:

```
private async void BtnStartCapture_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  BtnStartCapture.Enabled = false;
  try
  {
    for (int i = 1; i <= CaptureSettings.NoOfFrames; i++)
    {
      String currentFile;
      if (CaptureSettings.CkBoard1 == true)
      {
        currentFile = await Task.Run(() => CaptureSettings.CaptureFrame(1, i));
        fileNames.Add(currentFile);
      }

      if (CaptureSettings.CkBoard2 == true)
      {
        currentFile = await Task.Run(() => CaptureSettings.CaptureFrame(2, i));
        fileNames.Add(currentFile);
      }
    }
  }
  finally
  {
    BtnStartCapture.Enabled = true;
  }
}
```

> How do I cancel?

[Cancellation in .NET follows a standard pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads). The code being canceled observes a `CancellationToken`, which can be set from a `CancellationTokenSource`. Each `CancellationTokenSource` is a way to cancel the operation, but it can only be used once. So in this case, you want a new `CancellationTokenSource` each time the operation begins.

You *could* interpret a cancellation request as a kill request for your external process, but in your case I think it would be better to interpret the cancellation request as "let the current external process finish; just don't capture the next frame". I'm thinking this is better because the external process communicates with a hardware device (which we don't want to get into an unexpected state), and because it's fairly fast.

```
private CancellationTokenSource _cts;

private async void BtnStartCapture_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
  var token = _cts.Token;
  BtnStartCapture.Enabled = false;
  BtnCancelCapture.Enabled = true;
  try
  {
    for (int i = 1; i <= CaptureSettings.NoOfFrames; i++)
    {
      token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
      String currentFile;
      if (CaptureSettings.CkBoard1 == true)
      {
        currentFile = await Task.Run(() => CaptureSettings.CaptureFrame(1, i));
        fileNames.Add(currentFile);
      }

      if (CaptureSettings.CkBoard2 == true)
      {
        currentFile = await Task.Run(() => CaptureSettings.CaptureFrame(2, i));
        fileNames.Add(currentFile);
      }
    }
  }
  catch (OperationCanceledException)
  {
    // TODO: decide what to do here - clear fileNames? Display a message? Nothing?
  }
  finally
  {
    BtnStartCapture.Enabled = true;
    BtnCancelCapture.Enabled = false;
  }
}

private void BtnCancelCapture_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  _cts.Cancel();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following uses the Invoke and WaitForExit methods to achieve your desired result.

**Edit** I edited the below code so it would support "back to back" calls to the thread that starts the process.

```
    static readonly object _object = new object();
    public int iProcCount = 0;
    public void StartExe()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process proc;
        lock (_object) // Because WaitForExit is inside the lock all other 
                       // instances of this thread must wait before the 
                       // previous thread has finished
        {
            proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(strExePath);
            proc.WaitForExit(); // This is not on the UI thread so it will not block the UI thread
        }
        this.Invoke(new Action(() => UpdateGUI(this, "Finished Proc " + iProcCount)));
        iProcCount++;
    }

    public void UpdateGUI(Form theGui, string msg)
    { // This will wil update the GUI when the GUI thread is not busy
        lblGUIUpdate.Text = msg;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread th = new Thread(StartExe);
        th.Start(); // After this, the GUI thread will not block
    }
```

Comment: You still can hit the button twice before StartExe has finished, don't you?

Comment: If by "button" you mean the date time picker, then yes.

Comment: I mean you can start the process again, before the former execution has finished.

Comment: The question said "I've to wait for each process to finish before the next call ". But if you wanted that result just create a separate Process variable and call WaitForExit for each one after all "three" processes have started

Comment: So? If you hit the start button twice in a row, you have two threads firing up processes executing the external exe ...

Comment: Yes. And that is a problem here, because the executions on one thread are ok. But on two threads, they could overlap and probably will.

Comment: Do you notice the question says "back to back"? Fildor has a point here in that your answer does not address the usage scenario posed by the question...

Comment: Ok, but calling "MainMeth" once at the start of his program should do what he wants. Ill edit my answer. Thanks

Comment: Thanks guys for the input, I came up with a new solution using a lock.